# How to redirect user back to login form after signing up with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise to authenticate users. However, when a user signs up, they're not told to confirm their account, they just have to assume so.

In my Application Controller, I have the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:first_name, :last_name, :email]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end
end
```

In my case, the user is going to be redirected back to the login form, but there is no way to tell them to check their email. The only time they find this out is when they try to authenticate again, and then the default `devise` gem tells them they need to confirm their account before continuing.

I need to figure out a way to do this **after** the user signs up, but **before** they try to log in manually (some may not even do so because there is a lack of instructions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). Assuming, you have the routes setup for devise.

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

---

```
# registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_page_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't have routes currently set up. Based on this, I'm assuming I'd have to create a new controller with this information in it, and have devise to route sign ups to this controller?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: For some reason, it still does not work. It still gives me the default "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." rather than pausing at my `binding.pry` statement in this function. I did update the route too.

Comment: It's because you have `authenticate_user!` in `application_controller.rb`. That line causes the issue. It's like before registrations `create` action, it's checking if user is `signed in`, it'll obviously return `false`. Hence you're getting the error `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

Comment: Ahh, ok. Makes sense. I guess I need to figure out a workaround in this case then. I'd like the user to be authenticated prior to doing anything, but obviously not if they just signed up. Let me ask you this though... It seems like it's still registering the user, even if `authenticate_user!` results in the user not being authenticated. Is `authenticate_user!` still passing the parameters to sign the user up or something?

Comment: You can just put authenticate_user! on per controller basis and use `except` or `only` options to trigger it on actions.

Comment: So now this works, but now I'm getting an error for trying to call `confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)` from the view. :( I get the controller redirection, but this doesnt make any sense now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180170/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-lewlsauce).

Answer (score 0):

Just override [`Devise::RegistrationsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb).

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "my_registrations"}

class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  # this method would normally sign the user in
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    flash[:alert] = "You need to confirm your account."
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path 
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, and while I did not get an error, it did not override the controller. In fact, I put a binding.pry in the `def sign_up` method and it did not hit it. I did restart the server too. interesting.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. I don’t know exactly how but the instructions for overriding controllers are pretty clear. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md#configuring-controllers